# How can i import Tabdelimited text into the EPPlus sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I would like to use `EPPlus` to create an Excel file but I have a problem: my input data is in a tab-delimited format:

```
Name     Code     Grade
------------------------
N1       C22      17.6
N2       C09      18.9
N3       C18      20
```

How can I add this type (tab format) of data using `EPPlus` package?

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus is a library to read and write `xlsx` files only, so you cannot directly parse a file in tabular format.

You need to either write a reader for your format or, even easier, use a CSV reader that supports custom delimiters, and set the delimiter to `\t`. You can use this reader to read each cell of your data and feed it to EPPlus to re-create the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply read the text file in the standard old C# way, load each cell into a cell in EPPlus, and then save it. You'd just have to write a few loops and some formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

Epplus supports importing tab delimited text. You can see it sample9.cs (https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample9.cs)

If you are just looking for code,

```
//Create the format object to describe the text file
var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
format.Delimiter='\t'; //Tab

//Now read the file into the sheet.
Console.WriteLine("Load the text file...");
var csvDir = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "csv");

var range = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(Utils.GetFileInfo(csvDir, "Sample9-2.txt", false), format);
```

Direct link to the line # https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample9.cs#L138